# nghttp2: POST payload

Tags: http2, nghttp2

I am trying to POST a dataset using nghttp2. I noticed that the `nghttp2_submit_request` sends the `stream_user_data` just through header frame not the data frame.

What's the convenient method to submit a data (json or binary) using nghttp2?
Should I use `nghttp2_submit_data` or use asio `session.submit`?

Answer (score 1):

The `stream_user_data` is just a opaque pointer, and solely used by application to pass arbitrary data it wants to use in callback functions.

The expected way to send data is implement `nghttp2_data_source_read_callback` to send data in non-blocking way.  And set it to `nghttp2_data_provider`, and pass it to `nghttp2_submit_request`.

This is the same way to send response from server side.  Check https://nghttp2.org/documentation/tutorial-server.html to see how to implement `nghttp2_data_source_read_callback`.